# Probability of never returning to the origin until time $2n$ in asymmetric Bernoulli random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

I have the following asymmetric random walk problem.

> $X_1, \cdots, X_{2n} \overset{iid}{\sim} F(p)$, where $F(p) : \begin{cases} P(X = 1) = p \\ P(X = -1) = q=1-p\end{cases}$

So what I need to find is the probability of navigating only the positive side and never touching the starting point until the end, i.e.

> $\eta = P( S_i > 0, i=1, \cdots, 2n-1, S_{2n} \ge 0)$

It seems quite direct for the symmetric random-walk case. But the things seem quite tricky for this asymmetric case.

---

**My attempt**

$\eta = \sum_{r=1}^n P( S_i > 0, i=1, \cdots, 2n-1, S_{2n} \ge 2r) $

But I don't see any way to calculate each term $P( S_i > 0, i=1, \cdots, 2n-1, S_{2n} \ge 2r)$.